# When do we use the dot product for the product of two matrices as opposed to multiplying across?

Tags: linear-algebra

[Image of Linear Algebra Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6gqQ.jpg)

Hey everyone, I recently started learning Linear Algebra and I am confused when it comes to matrix multiplication. I attached an image of the work my question pertains to. I can't really seem to find the answer anywhere.

For Matrix AB, we do the product. However, for Matrix BA, we just multiply each entry across. For Matrix BA, why do we not do the dot product as well? Matrix AB is a 1x1 matrix and Matrix BA is a 3x3 matrix so the dimensions are the same.

Comment: There is a general procedure for multiplying two matrices. How was it explained to you?

Comment: For $BA$, we **are** taking the dot-product. However, the "dot-product" of two length-1 vectors is just the regular product. The rows of $B$ have length $1$, and so do the columns of $A$.